# Google App Engine 1.7.6 Remote API error

Tags: python, google-app-engine, remoteapi

Prior to the 1.7.6 dev server update, I was able to use /_ah/remote_api to upload test data to my dev server having to go through the authentication process by not entering a username and password (hitting return twice).  Since the update, this now continuously asks for a username and password, regardless of what I put in - often says error incorrect username or password.  I am currently targeting localhost:8080,

```
def auth_func():
  return (raw_input('Username:'), getpass.getpass('Password:'))

remote_api_stub.ConfigureRemoteApi(None, '/_ah/remote_api', auth_func,
                                   'localhost:8080')
```

though there are two new servers including the API server and the admin server.  Has anyone else encountered this?  if so, how did you fix it?

Thanks!
Jon

Comment: it checks that the email/username has an @ in it.
I just type x@x and password x

Comment: that's weird cause I tried an email password combination and it didn;t work.... but now it did.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently thanks to Tim - If you use the new dev_appserver then you need to sepecify a email like looking username and a single character as a password on the local development server in order for it to accept and move past the login stage.